# How to set MenuItems to fit equal space in the Menu?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have such a XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFPlayground"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Menu Grid.Row="0">
            <MenuItem 
                Background="Green"
                Header="First"/>    
            <MenuItem 
                Background="Yellow"
                Header="Second"/>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I run it I got such a result

[image]

I need to set these items equally inside the `Menu`, like the `First button takes 50% and the` Second`one also takes 50%, horizontally and vertically respectively. And text`First`and`Second` also should take a place at the center of the button.

Whatever I have done nothing is helps, I can set fix height or weight, but there is no way to set something like

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
```

It is just doesn't work

**P.S.** I know there are other possible approaches something like using another view, but I need to use `Menu` which should contain 4 or 5 items... (Just for this example I build Menu example where it is 2)

**UPD**

Following @BionicCode answer there is what I got

```
<Window x:Class="PlaygroundWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PlaygroundWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStopCollection>
                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}" Offset="0.0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}" Offset="1.0" />
                                        </GradientStopCollection>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>

                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>

                            <WrapPanel ItemWidth="200" 
                     ClipToBounds="True"
                     IsItemsHost="True" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Menu Grid.Row="1">
            <MenuItem 
                Background="Green"
                Header="First"/>
            <MenuItem 
                Background="Yellow"
                Header="Second"/>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

There are three issues

1. In the example I have two items and they should take equally entire space horizontally
2. In the example I have two items and they should take equally entire space vertically (according to the grid 20%)
3. Text on the items (first, second) should be centered, currently, it is aligned left

**UPD2**

Currently my XAML implementation is:

```
<Window x:Class="PlaygroundWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PlaygroundWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStopCollection>
                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}" Offset="0.0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}" Offset="1.0" />
                                        </GradientStopCollection>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>

                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>

                            <UniformGrid  
                     ClipToBounds="True"
                     IsItemsHost="True" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Menu Grid.Row="1">
            <MenuItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                      Background="Green"
                      Header="Top Level Item" />

            <MenuItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                      Background="Yellow"
                      Header="Top Level Header">
                <MenuItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Header="Submenu Item" />

                <MenuItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Header="Submenu Header">
                    <MenuItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Header="Submenu Item" />
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and it looks like this

[image]

**BUT** if I add one more item

- The desired result is: the item will be added to the same line like the third item in the sequence and take the space equally
- Actual result (see screenshot below) the item moves on the next line

[image]

Actually, there are two issues: **the first** as I described that item moves on the next line and **the second** one is that text on the item itself is not centered (it alight on the left instead).

It is problems that I am trying to explain from the beginning of the question.

Comment: I would say that you have to look at the template for this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/menu-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the default template for the `Menu` and replace the items host.

The default host is a `StackPanel` which always assigns the mimimum required space to each child.
To automatically spreadout the available space evenly, you can use the `UniformGrid` or the `WrapPanel` instead

The following `Style` is taken from [Microsoft Docs: Menu Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/menu-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#menu-and-menuitem-controltemplate-example). but you can easily extract the style using the XAML Designer or Blend.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
        <Border BorderThickness="1">
          <Border.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
              <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}" Offset="0.0" />
                  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}" Offset="1.0" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
              </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>

          </Border.BorderBrush>
          <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
              <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" Offset="0" />
              <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
          </Border.Background>
          
          <WrapPanel ItemWidth="200" 
                     ClipToBounds="True"
                     IsItemsHost="True" />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

To center the content of the `MenuItem.Header` you have to override the default template of the MenuItem. Add the following template to a `ResourceDictionary` within the scopw of the targeted `MenuItem` (e.g., `Window.Resources` or *App.xaml*). Since the template overrides the resource ky, they will apply automatically.

Note that if your top level `MenuItem` does not contain child items, you must change the `x:Key` identifier of the template to `{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}`.

The pattern to center the `MenuItem` content is to find the hosting `ContentPresenter` in the corresponding item level template and modify it by bindng the `ContentPresenter.HorizontalAlignment` to the templated parent's `MenuItem.HorizontalContentAlignment` e.g. by using `TemplateBinding`.
After defining the template override you simply have to center the item's content using the `MenuItem.HorizontalContentAlignment` property.:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}"
                 TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
  <Border x:Name="Border" 
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <Grid>
      <ContentPresenter Margin="6,3,6,3"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        ContentSource="Header"
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
      <Popup x:Name="Popup"
            Placement="Bottom"
            IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
            AllowsTransparency="True"
            Focusable="False"
            PopupAnimation="Fade">
        <Border x:Name="SubmenuBorder"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    Background="{DynamicResource MenuPopupBrush}">
          <Border.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
          </Border.BorderBrush>
          <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True"
                                    >
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
          </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
      </Popup>
    </Grid>
  </Border>
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation"
                Value="true">
      <Setter TargetName="Popup"
                Property="PopupAnimation"
                Value="None" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted"
                Value="true">
      <Setter TargetName="Border"
                Property="BorderBrush"
                Value="Transparent" />
      <Setter Property="Background"
                TargetName="Border">
        <Setter.Value>
          <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                                    EndPoint="0,1">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
              <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource ControlLightColor}" />
                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}"
                                                Offset="1.0" />
              </GradientStopCollection>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
          </LinearGradientBrush>

        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger SourceName="Popup"
                Property="AllowsTransparency"
                Value="True">
      <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder"
                Property="CornerRadius"
                Value="0,0,4,4" />
      <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder"
                Property="Padding"
                Value="0,0,0,3" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                Value="False">
      <Setter Property="Foreground">
        <Setter.Value>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

### Example

The `MenuItem.Header` property value of the items is chosen to give you a hint which template/style key you have to chos. Visit [Microsoft Docs: Menu and MenuItem ControlTemplate Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/menu-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to find the required styles and templates and the required `x:Key` identifiers. You can modify them (like I did by replacing the `StackPanel` of the `Menu` style with a `WrapPanel` or `UniformGrid`).
Add the styles and templates to a ResourceDictionary within the scope of the Menu (e.g., App.xaml).

```
<Menu>
  <MenuItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Header="Top Level Item" />

  <MenuItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Header="Top Level Header">
    <MenuItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Header="Submenu Item" />

    <MenuItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Header="Submenu Header">
      <MenuItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Header="Submenu Item" />
    </MenuItem>
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't help, I updated my question, please take a look

Comment: It's in my answer. When investigate the code of the Menu Style then you se that the hosting Panel is a WrapPanel with an item width of 200. Due to this width setting the items won't stretch of course. If you want them to stretch evenly to occupy available  space use the UniformGrid instead. To see how to center the header content see the updated answer.

Comment: Sometimes WPF tries to make your life much harder, such things as making the item to occupate the space equally and set text at the middle of the view requires a really deep understanding in XAML and tons of lines of code... Anyway, the example you provided doesn't work :( , and another issue as I said in the question I need to support 4 or 5 menu items (it is kind of dynamic) just for an example I provided 2 items... but your example doesn't support 4 or 5, it is just moving next items on the next line. Or I missed something? Maybe you can post a full example of XAML (not just styles)?

Comment: I don't think you are rignt. You are just using the Menu control in a very uncommon way. According to UX design rules menu buttons should be easily accessible. That deadspace you have to stretch smaller items adds a comfort penalty due to longer mouse movements. Aside from the bad feel it looks odd.

Comment: My example works 100% Have you replaced the WrapPanel with the UniformGrid like I told you? Also pay attention to use the proper key for the template and styles - like I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I have added an example of the trivial solution. I hope it helps to show you what you have to do.

Comment: Please read the answer carefully again. If still have problems to understand what to do then I will try to explain it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... I posted UPD2 with the entire code you posted, there are still the same two issues that we started, could you please take a look?